# I want to create a powershell script to extact data from a server date wise

Tags: windows, powershell

we have server where one day file created in 24 sections its basically a t02 file. and some time if our stations where down then these file may miss. we have more then 400 stations so each day one station should create 24 files. so there would so many files with different station folder name their in the server everyday.
the path be like : `Y:\Alloy\DEHRADUN\2022\01`
so in that alloy folder had dehradun folder and 2022 is the year and 01 is month(January)

I have already have a script from which i can extact data files number in csv:

```
$targDir = "Y:\Alloy\DEHRADUN\";
Get-ChildItem -Path $sub –Recurse *.T02 | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Select FullName,Name,LastWriteTime,Length| Export-Csv "C:\Reports\YearWise\Dehradun2022.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

and that code will get me all the data with date and size of the 24 files per day.

But i'm stuck that if anyday some files are missing then i will not read those and it created only files which are in the folder,

so do we have any code so it can also read the missing files as "no file".

for example if folder have 20 files and 4 files missed then i will show that these files are not present.

please help me on this.

I have tried below powershell script to get the data, but only give the file data which is present in the server folder. i'm expecting that i can create a script where i can also see the missing files also in the generated csv file

```
$targDir = "Y:\Alloy\DEHRADUN\";
Get-ChildItem -Path $sub –Recurse *.T02 | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Select FullName,Name,LastWriteTime,Length| Export-Csv "C:\Reports\YearWise\Dehradun2022.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: How is this related to Python or PHP?

Comment: can we extract data by python ? i don't know

Comment: Probably, but don't just tag random languages...you could tag all of them if you're going to do that, since they could likely all do the same job. Just tag the one you're actually writing the code in, right now. Please read [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) alongside [ask] and the [tour]. Thanks

Comment: thankyou adyson, i will keep in mind.

Comment: You need to create an array of the 24 files for each day $filenames24.  Then use contains to check if file exists : folderFilename | foreach {-not $filenames24.Contains($)}

Comment: thanks @jdweng for your suggestion, can you write down the full code. I'm bit confused and can't execute the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$files = @("file2", "file1", "file2", "file4", "file5", "test.txt")
[string[]]$filenames = @()
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp" | foreach { $filenames += $_.Name }
$files | Where { -not $filenames.Contains($_) } | foreach { Write-Host "file not found" $_ }
```